# How do I make my character's walk animation stop when he jumps?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I have this problem because, when my character jumps he reproduces the walking and jumping animation ends up giving an error, and in the end my character hangs in a position.

blender 2.79

[image]

Comment: Are you using python or logic bricks for the animations? (could you also upload the.blend file??)..would make it a lot easier to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you don't add any layer for the jump animation.

**What's the meaning of layers in animations?**

This is something like Photoshop projects, for example: layer1 is not appearing because there is another layer on top of it which is layer 2.

**How can I add a layer or delete a layer in animation?**

In the *action actuator* Here :

[image]

This is the layer what the animation is. In your case make the animation layer 2.

**What about Deleting a layer?**

You can't delete a layer. you can delete the actuator. You can just change the layer.